# What is wrong with ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: asp.net

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirectScript", "window.location.href='Thankyou.aspx?'Service=" + hidService.Value  + ";",true);
```

Getting error: Expected ;

Please help me

Comment: i dont think it's the problem, but you do have an extra ' after your ? and before Service=, shouldnt that be after hidService.Value ?

Comment: Did you mean 

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirectScript", "window.location.href='Thankyou.aspx?Service=" + hidService.Value + "';"  ,true);

But i am getting the same error

Comment: This is a compile error or a javascript error? I dont see a problem with that line, are you sure that's the line the error is on?

Comment: Try this 
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirectScript", "window.location.href='Thankyou.aspx?Service=" + hidService.Value + "';",true);

Comment: @priyanka and @Radhi - You should never use this.GetType() as a key for registering your javascripts.  See http://blogs.ipona.com/james/archive/2006/10/03/6710.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your quotes are a little messed up, try:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirectScript",
    "window.location.href='Thankyou.aspx?Service=" + hidService.Value + "';", true);
```

You had a single quote after your `Service=` and it should have been just before your `;`.